# How to replace seome elements with a new element within a transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I will like to modify an XML document according to a logic per XML Copy transformation:

Input XML

```
<Request>
        <Parameters>

            <Parameter ID="SpecialDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="6.00"/>
            <Parameter ID="AccessoryDiscount" Changed="false" Value="0.00"/>
            <Parameter ID="AccessoryDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="0"/>
            <Parameter ID="BulkDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="4.0"/>
        </Parameters>
    </Product>
</Request>
```

Expected Output XML

```
<Request>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter ID="AccessoryDiscount" Changed="false" Value="0.00"/>
            <Parameter ID="AccessoryDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="0"/>
            <Parameter ID="totalDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="10.0"/>
        </Parameters>
    </Product>
</Request>
```

if there is any of Parameter[@ID='SpecialDiscountPercent'] or Paramete[@ID='BulkDiscountPercent'] within the input XML File, then i will like to have in the Output XML a new XML Element Parameter[@ID='totalDiscountPercent'] which will hold the sum of 'SpecialDiscountPercent' and 'BulkDiscountPercent'. Both Parameter[@ID='SpecialDiscountPercent'] and Paramete[@ID='BulkDiscountPercent'] should not appear in the final XML in this case. how do i achieve this? thank you for any Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but here's one way to do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parameters">
    <xsl:variable name="specialDiscounts"
                  select="Parameter[@ID = 'SpecialDiscountPercent' or
                                    @ID = 'BulkDiscountPercent']" />

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[count(. | $specialDiscounts) != 
                                               count($specialDiscounts)]" />
      <xsl:if test="$specialDiscounts">
        <Parameter ID="totalDiscountPercent" Changed="false"
                   Value="{format-number(sum($specialDiscounts/@Value), '0.0')}" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input (once the stray `</Products>` is removed), the result is:

```
<Request>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter ID="AccessoryDiscount" Changed="false" Value="0.00" />
    <Parameter ID="AccessoryDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="0" />
    <Parameter ID="totalDiscountPercent" Changed="false" Value="10.0" />
  </Parameters>
</Request>
```

Comment: Hi JLRishe, thank you very much. It works as expected! I can´t realy get you at some point. Can you please explain this line? <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[count(. | $specialDiscounts) !=                                             count($specialDiscounts)]" />
Many Thanks!

Comment: That line effectively means "apply templates to all attributes and child nodes that are _not_ in `$specialDiscounts`. The `|` symbol is the union operator, so when the node under examination is in `$specialDiscounts`, then `count(. | $specialDiscounts)` will be equal to `count($specialDiscounts)` (because they are the same set). We want to apply templates to the nodes for which that is _not_ true, hence `count(. | $specialDiscounts) != count($specialDiscounts)`.